# Android - height of multiline button with layout_weight set

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have the following layout for my dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/practice_question" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_select_question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_select_answers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_select_board_button"
            style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/practice_look_board" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_select_answer_button"
            style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/practice_answer" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

There is a problem with bottom buttons:
[image: Problem]

I want the first button not to be cropped. I've set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` but that doesn't helped.

P.S. If I change button text from "Look on the board" to "Look on the\nboard" all works fine. But I want to make the second button optional, so the first button may match the whole parent's width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed some of your code please try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_select_title"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/practice_question" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_select_question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_select_title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_select_answers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_select_question" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_select_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_select_answers"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_select_board_button"
            style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/practice_look_board" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_select_answer_button"
            style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/practice_answer" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your solution alwost works. Please look at my question's edit. I'll accept your answer since the problem will be fixed.

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev remove android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_select_answers" in list view and add android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_select_answers" in linearlayout. I am trying to implement this at my end. Please try you too and let me know it is working or not.

Comment: Yes, it works! I'll post the right layout as an edit to your answer.

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev Glad to hear you found your answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please approve my edit. I removed `alignParentBottom` attribute and it works with your corrections.